# $Q(\mathbb{Z}[t]) / \mathbb{Z}[t]$ is not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

I am doing this exercise:

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[t]$ and let $K$ be its fraction field. Show that the $R$ module $K/R$ is divisible but not injective.

I have done the divisible part, but I am stuck on the injective part, any hint ?

Comment: Try injecting $K$ into $\mathbb Q(t)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divisible implies injective only if R is a PID. Here that is not the case, so the counterexample should reflect that.

Because the submodule $J_1=\langle 2\rangle\subset R$ is free, we have a homomorphism $f:J\to K/R$ defined by $f(2)=\dfrac1t+R$. We can glue this together with the zero $R$-module homomorphism from $J_2=\langle t\rangle$ to $K/R$, because $J_2\cap J_1=\langle 2t\rangle$ and
$f(J_2\cap J_1)=0$. Thus we get a homomorphism from $I=J_1+J_2$ to $K/R$ that I denote by $f$ as well. Note that $I$ is not a principal ideal.

Non-injectivity of $K/R$ will follow, if we can show that $f:I\to K/R$ cannot be extended to a homomorphism of $R$-modules $\tilde{f}:R\to K/R$. $R$ is also a free module, so it suffices to prove that no compatible choice for $\tilde{f}(1)$ exists.

Can you do that?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand this point: $J_1 = <2> $ and $J_2 = <2> $ ?

Comment: ah ok you have edited

Comment: Sorry. It was a stupid typo.

Comment: ok, we obtain $\tilde{f}(1) = \frac{1}{2t} + R $ but also $t \tilde{f}(1) \in R $ which is impossible

Comment: I only concluded that $\tilde{f}(1)\in\dfrac1{2t}+\dfrac12R$ and $t\tilde{f}(1)\in R$, but that is still impossible :-)

Comment: yes $ \tilde{f}(1) \in \frac{1}{2t} + \frac{1}{2}R $